# Syntax Error "syntax error, unexpected tIDENTIFIER, expecting =>"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, validation

I'm working with a Hydra project that uses the curate gem for ruby and rails.

There is a current bug in our code when users are uploading new works, if they add a single space, " ", to any of the required fields, the app crashes and throws a stack trace. Obviously we can't have this in the production code, we need it to throw an invalid input error.

So I started reading about Ruby's validation system with the different validation filters and found a few validators that I think can help me with this, however the format of our code and that of the example docs on the RoR website is different.

I'm rather new to Ruby and Rails in general and haven't been working with the code base for very long. The format on the RoR site goes something like this:

```
  class Coffee < ActiveRecord::Base
    validates :size, inclusion: { in: %w(small medium large),
    message: "%{value} is not a valid size" }
  end
```

while our code is this in the generic_work.rb file:

```
class GenericWork < ActiveFedora::Base

    attribute :title,
        datastream: :descMetadata, multiple: false,
        validates: { presence: { message: 'Your article must have a title.' } }
end
```

Now, the validation itself is fine, and it works well. But when I try to add my own condition to account for single spaces in the title field, it throws the syntax error:

```
syntax error, unexpected tIDENTIFIER, expecting => validates: { :title format: { without: ^\s+$, message:
```

The full syntax of my custom validator is:

```
attribute :title,
    datastream: :descMetadata, multiple: false,
    validates: { :title, format: { without: ^\s+$, message: "no spaces"} }
```

I'm sure it's because I don't understand the different syntax our app uses, but for the life of e I can't figure out how to format the code.

Also when I get the validator to work, I'm sure there will be an issue with the RegEx I used to target the space. If anyone knows a validator better suited for this use case, I would be most grateful to you.

For FYI: Here is the full trace I get from the error:

```
syntax error, unexpected tIDENTIFIER, expecting => validates: { :title format: { without: ^\s+$, message: ... ^    
/home/kyle/workspace/curate/app/repository_models/generic_work.rb:91: syntax error, unexpected tIDENTIFIER, expecting keyword_end ...rmat: { without: ^\s+$, message: "no spaces"} } ... ^ 
/home/kyle/workspace/curate/app/repository_models/generic_work.rb:91: syntax error, unexpected '}', expecting keyword_end ...t: ^\s+$, message: "no spaces"} }
```

Comment: `{ :title, format: { without: ^\s+$, message: "no spaces"} }` isn't a Hash, do you perhaps want `{ :title => { format: { without: ^\s+$, message: "no spaces"} } }` or similar?

Comment: Doing that throws this: syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting keyword_end validates: { :title => { format: { with...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know Hydra, but if this example is valid syntax:

```
attribute :title,
  datastream: :descMetadata, multiple: false,
  validates: { presence: { message: 'Your article must have a title.' } }
```

Then this example has an invalid hash in the third line and an invalid regexp (as Vasfed already pointed out):

```
attribute :title,
  datastream: :descMetadata, multiple: false,
  validates: { :title, format: { without: ^\s+$, message: "no spaces" } }
```

I would try to fix that by removing the duplicate `:title`:

```
attribute :title,
  datastream: :descMetadata, multiple: false,
  validates: { format: { without: /^\s+$/, message: "no spaces" } }
```

Comment: Thank you for actually helping me. A simple "your hash syntax is wrong" is all I needed. Thank you :),

Answer (score 1):

You're missing regex delimiters:

```
validates: { :title, format: { without: ^\s+$, message: "no spaces"} }
```

should be

```
validates: { :title, format: { without: /^\s+$/, message: "no spaces"} }
```

Comment: It was missing, thank you. But it did not fix the issue, same error.